# Como posso relacionar tabelas com retorno em json com php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-service, api

Por favor, uma ajuda, sou nova em programação e estou precisando fazer um relacionamento de tabela *MySQL*, com retorno em *JSON*, eu tentei o seguinte código, mas está com erros. Já pesquisei muito no *Google* e *Youtube*, mas não consegui achar nada parecido.

Código:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$con = new mysqli('mysql.meusite.com.br', 'meubanco', 'senha', 'meubanco');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
    $sql = "SELECT refeicao.nome, refeicao.id FROM refeicao_refeicao AS refeicao
                INNER JOIN refeicao_alimento AS opcao
                INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao AS cardapio
                WHERE cardapio.id_refeicao = refeicao.id
                AND cardapio.id_alimentos = opcao.id
                GROUP BY refeicao.id";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $arr = Array();

        if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
            while($dados = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                $arr[0] = $dados->id;
                $arr[1] = $dados->nome;
                $arr[2] = $id_refeicao;
        }
            $sql2 = "SELECT refeicao_alimento.nome
                FROM refeicao_alimento 
                INNER JOIN refeicao_refeicao
                INNER JOIN alimentos_refeicao
                WHERE alimentos_refeicao.id_alimentos = refeicao_alimento.id
                AND alimentos_refeicao.id_refeicao = $id_refeicao
                GROUP BY refeicao_alimento.id";
            $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
            $arr2 = Array();

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
                while($dados2 = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                    $arr2[0] = $dados2->nome;
            }


    }    
echo json_encode();
//print_r($JSON);
}
?>
```

Erro inicial:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): No such file or directory in <b>/home/qualitserv/www/api/apiCardapios.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/qualitserv/www/api/apiCardapios.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/qualitserv/www/api/apiCardapios.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

Eu já uso essa mesma estrutura *SQL* no meu sistema onde cadastro os dados, mas acredito que para *API*, deve funcionar de forma diferente! Obrigada!

Comment: No arquivo `apiCardapios.php` altere tudo o que começa com `mysql_` para `mysqli_`. Esse código que está na pergunta, é do arquivo  `apiCardapios.php`?

Comment: Recomendo que você veja essa pergunta [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/60376).

Comment: Na verdade foi uma tentativa, preciso buscar as opções de cardápio que estão em uma tabela, conforme o cliente selecionar a refeição, que está em outra tabela, no meu sistema, onde insiro as opções e refeições está esse código, mas para a api, não to sabendo como fazer, troquei por mysqli, como sugeriu, mas continua com erros!

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description) do *MySQLi*, você pode usar o método `query` de dois jeitos:

> *Estilo procedural* é esse o qual você está a utilizar.

```
$con = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
$qry = "SELECT id, nome, email FROM perfil";
/* Verifica a conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falha na conexão com a base de dados: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry); // Executa a query e armazena seu resultado
printf("Retornou %d cadastros.\n", mysqli_num_rows($res)); // Imprime na tela a quantidade de registros encontrado na tabela
```

O seu problema está justamente na hora de usar o método `mysqli_query` veja que no exemplo acima, o mesmo recebe dois parâmetros, pois no estilo procedural é necessário que seja informado o parâmetro `$link`.

> *Estilo orientado à objeto*.

```
$con = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
$qry = "SELECT id, nome, email FROM perfil";
/* Verifica a conexão */
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falha na conexão com a base de dados: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$res = $con->query($qry); // Executa a query e armazena seu resultado
printf("Retornou %d cadastros.\n", $res->num_rows); // Imprime na tela a quantidade de registros encontrado na tabela
```

### Referência

- [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description)
- [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description)